# Wubi won't start on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: wubi

I have got latest wubi. And when i run it it asks me for admin privilidges, and then nothing happens. I read that u have do something with python at system paths. But I don't have any python on that paths. What I should do now?

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are trying to install?

Comment: Where did you get wubi from? can you link the url?

Answer (score 0):

You had mentioned

> it asks me for admin privileges.

Right click wubi.exe and select Run as Administrator.
Hopefully, it should work.